# What do the colours of the souls mean in Dororo?

Tags: dororo

So apparently Hyakkimaru and Biwamaru see white to a soul which is pure, and see red the soul of someone who has killed other humans or monsters who are evil. Are there other colour meanings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is just gray, that is a normal human, White means a human with a pure soul, red means a ghoul or a demon you see it for the first time in episode 1.  gray with red lines means a human who killed people it's first seen in episode 5. In episode 12 you see a green soul. This from the statue (the god). Green is probarly wood. In episode 16 you see that a tree also has a green soul and the right arm of hyakimaru is also green.

In episode 13, there is 1 new color,

> a soul that was gray with black holes, this was a human that was revived from the death by a demon.

In episode 14, there are 2 new colors,

> the color blue and yellow. If I have to guess those are ghosts that are killed people.

Comment: Blue and yellow appeared in the last episode (#14)

Comment: @Pablo true but I didn't know back then and we still don't know what blue and yellow means

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you add each episode number when they introduced new colors (including for gray, white, gray with red lines, and red)?

Comment: @AkiTanaka i will try!

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answer, there is also in episode 7 the orange color for a demon with a kind soul.